# How to re-enable click event on a div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, dom-events

Given the following code:

```
    if ($selector.html().indexOf("radio") > 0) {

        if ($oldSelected != null) {
            // enable clicks on old selected radio button
            $oldSelected.children().bind('click', function () { return true; });
        }

        // disable click on selected 
        $selector.children().bind('click', function () { return false; });
        $oldSelected = $selector;
    }
```

The disabling code works fine.  Once executed the element is no longer clickable.  However, when trying to re-enable the click event, nothing happens.

Suggestions?

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just binding click handlers over and over again. You need to `unbind()` the ones you don't want active.

Try this:

```
$oldSelected.children().unbind('click').bind('click', function () { return true; });
```

On second thought, `unbind('click')` may be all you need if there's no other logic in your click handlers.

Comment: As I mentioned the disabling the click works fine.  Do you have an example of what you are suggesting?

Comment: The disabling works because you have one click handler that returns false. The enabling doesn't work because you still have a click handler that returns false. `.bind('click', newfunction)` doesn't remove any existing click handlers.

Comment: So why is it that `.bind('click', function () { return true; }` doesn't just re-enable the clickable event?  Am I not changing that click handler to return true?

Comment: _"Am I not changing that click handler to return true?"_ - No, you are adding an *additional* click handler. You are not changing or removing any existing click handlers. See my edit.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying now.  You're removing the click added (false) click binding, then adding a new (true) click binding.  Works too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var handler = function () {
    // do some stuff
};

// First
el.bind('click', handler);

// Later on...
el.unbind('click', handler);
```

Remember to save the callback so that later on you can unbind. [Unbind docs](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).